# Move SVN Repository without Console Access

Tags: svn

Is it possible to move a SVN repository to a new server, including all history, without console access to the server (*svnadmin dump* is not an option)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to the repository directly via something like ftp?  Can you just copy the file somewhere else?

If you are unable to copy files then one thing you could do is use git-svn to copy the contents of the old repository into a new one.  I believe anyone using the repository would have to do a clean checkout from the new repository if you use this method.

Here is an [article](http://blog.venthur.de/2009/04/08/migrating-a-project-from-one-svn-repository-to-another-using-git-svn/) describing the processes.

Another option is [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html).

Comment: Seems to be working so far... I'll provide more feedback once the (very large) repository is finished copying.

Comment: After hours of processing, it stopped with the following error:

r14293 = 74f77061e085420d80ee03f61d05070c9fb1a881 (git-svn)
RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/svn/repo/!svn/vcc/defa
ult': REPORT of '/svn/repo/!svn/vcc/default': could not connect to server
(http://svn.myrepo.com) at C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4567

It seems there was an intermittent loss of connectivity to the server.  Is there any way to gracefully continue, or do I need to restart?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about that.

Comment: Worked after restarting a few times.  Note that svnsync did not work because "Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges" (error listed in manual) and it's not practical to change the configuration (especially since git method worked).